# How to reverse a list in R?

Tags: r, list, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a list with function `list.reverse`. I run an example from its [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlist/versions/0.4.6.1/topics/list.reverse).

```
x <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
list.reverse(x)
```

R returns an error message "Error in list.reverse(x) : could not find function "list.reverse" ".

Comment: The page you link shows a function from the rlist package.  Did you install and load that package?  Please edit your question so it's not complaining about the documentation unless you did that.

Comment: @Elin you are right. I've not installed that package. But how do I know to install that package when there is no such information on that documentation link.

Comment: It's right there on the top right of the page.

Comment: @Elin I'm sorry. It's my fault.

Comment: If you rewrite the question as "how do I reverse a list" then it is a reasonable question.

Comment: You should either close this question or rewrite it so that the answers you got make sense.  Also please note that the website you linked is not "official" it is run by a for profit company.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function does work. You have not loaded or installed `rlist`.

Try :

```
rlist::list.reverse(x)

#$c
#[1] 3

#$b
#[1] 2

#$a
#[1] 1
```

and so does base R `rev` works :

```
rev(x)

#$c
#[1] 3

#$b
#[1] 2

#$a
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this `base R` solution:

```
#Data
x <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
#Reverse
x[rev(1:length(x))]
```

Output:

```
$c
[1] 3

$b
[1] 2

$a
[1] 1
```

And using the function you mentioned, first load the package:

```
library(rlist)
#Code
x <- list(a=1,b=2,c=3)
list.reverse(x)
```

Output:

```
$c
[1] 3

$b
[1] 2

$a
[1] 1
```

Comment: `rev()` works on lists, so your first suggestion is unnecessarily complicated. Maybe this was not the case in older versions of R?